# Storage Usage Discrepancy

Tags: event, data-storage

I am seeing Events listed in Current Data Storage Usage, however using dev console, I see nothing in the events table.  Is there somewhere I should be looking to find these events? Any info will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you check the recycle bin?

Comment: Yep, nothing there.

Comment: Do you have a custom object named Events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was solved - The culprit ended up being archived events.  Thanks all!